# Help with derivation step in Kepler orbit, using chain rule

Tags: physics, implicit-differentiation, chain-rule

[Picture of equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccfVr.png)

Hello, I am trying to work out the derivation of the Kepler orbit myself with help of the following wiki article, [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_orbit#Mathematical_solution_of_the_differential_equation_(1)_above):

In the picture above, I'm unsure how differentiating equation 5 with respect to $t$ produces equation 6. I tried using product rule:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dr}{dt}\right)=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dr}{dθ}\cdot\frac{dθ}{dt}\right)$$
$$\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}=\left(\frac{dr}{dθ}\right)'\frac{dθ}{dt}+\frac{dr}{dθ}\left(\frac{dθ}{dt}\right)'$$
$$\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}=\frac{d^2r}{dθ^2}\left(\frac{dθ}{dt}\right)^2+\frac{dr}{dθ}\frac{dθ}{dt^2}$$

Precisely, I don't understand how $\displaystyle{\left(\frac{dr}{dθ}\right)'\frac{dθ}{dt}}$ becomes $\displaystyle{\frac{d^2r}{dθ^2}\left(\frac{dθ}{dt}\right)^2}$.

Comment: It's the same step as you have in the first line: $f' = \frac{d\theta}{dt}\frac{df}{d\theta}$. Remember that $\frac{d}{d\theta}(\frac{dr}{d\theta}) = \frac{d^2r}{d\theta^2}$

Comment: Because r is function of $\theta$

Comment: Next time, please take the time to type in the other equations instead of posting a picture of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Chain Rule
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)=\frac{d\theta}{dt}\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right).$$

Comment: Ok that makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $y=f(x)$, then
$$\dot y = {dy\over dt}={dy\over dx}\cdot{dx\over dt}={dy\over dx}\dot x.$$
Here, let $x$ be $\theta$ and $y$ be $\frac{dr}{d\theta}$.